# how to addAttributes to an array of strings?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsrange

I encountered a problem here. I would like to `addAttributes` to strings I collected from an array. How do I go about it from my incomplete function?

EDITED: the code works alright but just as @Larme said, by using `range`, the attribute text will only append to the **first** range found, not the rest.
For example, if the text is `Desmond is careless, I am <b>desmond<b> with a <b>car<b>` the end result will be **Desmond** is **car**eless, I am desmond with a car any idea how to find the range index with repeated append?

```
 func find(inText text: String, pattern: String) -> [String]?
    {
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:pattern+"(.*?)"+pattern, options: [])
        var results = [String]()

        regex.enumerateMatches(in: text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, text.utf16.count))
        { result, flags, stop in
            if let r = result?.range(at: 1),
               let range = Range(r, in: text)
            {
                results.append(String(text[range]))
            }
        }
        return results
    }

   let colorAttribute =
        [NSAttributedStringKey.font: Fonts.OpenSansSemibold(isPhoneSE ? 13 :isPhone3 ? 12 : 16),
         NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: Colors.slate] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]

    ***EDITED***

    let boldStrArray = find(inText: item.inbox_body, pattern: "<b>") // find the bold text

    let replaceStr = item.inbox_body!.replacingOccurrences(of: "<b>", with: "")

    print(boldStrArray) //["desmond", "car"]
    print(replaceStr)

    let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: replaceStr, attributes: normalAttribute)

    for b in boldStrArray!
    {
        let range = (replaceStr as! NSMutableString).range(of: b)
        print(range)
        attrStr.setAttributes(colorAttribute, range: range)
        //attrStr.addAttributes(colorAttribute, range: range)
    }
```

any comments are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `find(inText:, pattern:)` being? I think that method could improved to return range instead of words. And then it would be simpler.

Comment: You can find range simply with `let range = (attrStr.string as NSString).range(of: b)`, code might need some update though

Comment: Also if you have `I'm careless, I am <b>desmond<b> with a <b>car<b>` you might find an issue.`

Comment: @Larme added the find code i referred from SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be easier if `find(inText:pattern:)` returns `(NS)Range`s (or assimilated even better `NSTextCheckingResult`s).

So with some modifications:

```
func find(inText text: String, pattern: String) -> [NSTextCheckingResult] {
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:pattern+"(.*?)"+pattern, options: []) //There should be a try/catch at least
    return regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))
}
```

I used my "own font & color", because I don't have your settings.
Because it's not easily guessable that you can use the `range(at: 1)` depending on the pattern you use, I wouldn't use a method but write it inside it.

```
let initialString = "I am <b>desmond<b> with a <b>car<b>"
let colorAttribute: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12),
                                                     .foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

var attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: initialString)
print("BEFORE attrStr: \(attrStr)")
let boldRanges = find(inText: initialString, pattern: "<b>")
boldRanges.reversed().forEach { (aResult) in
    let subTextNSRange = aResult.range(at: 1)
    guard let subTextRange = Range(subTextNSRange, in: attrStr.string) else { return } //This is to "switch" between NSRange & Range
    let replacementString = String(attrStr.string[subTextRange])
    let replacementAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: replacementString, attributes: colorAttribute)
    attrStr.replaceCharacters(in: aResult.range, with: replacementAttributedString)
}
print("AFTER attrStr: \(attrStr)")
```

Output:

```
$> BEFORE attrStr: I am <b>desmond<b> with a <b>car<b>{
}
$> AFTER attrStr: I am {
}desmond{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 1 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\".AppleSystemUIFontBold 12.00 pt. P [] (0x60c000051e50) fobj=0x101a36cf0, spc=3.09\"";
} with a {
}car{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 1 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\".AppleSystemUIFontBold 12.00 pt. P [] (0x60c000051e50) fobj=0x101a36cf0, spc=3.09\"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is an attributed string")

    let range = attrString.mutableString.range(of: "attributed")

    attrString.setAttributes([:], range: range)
```